# Jquery Datatable Dialog - Dialog is opening only the first one

Tags: jquery, dialog, datatable

I'm currently working with DataTable and dialogue. However, seems the dialog window to open only on the first click. Each additional click opens the website but not the dialog window.

Can any one see the failure? The Code as follow

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function DialogInformation() {
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: $link.attr('title'),
                width: 800,
                height: 400,
                modal: true,
                open: function ()
                {
                    $(this).load($link.attr('href'));
                }
            });
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        return false;
    };

    $('##named_datatable').dataTable( {
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "bInfo" : false,
        "bProcessing": false,
            "bServerSide": false,
        "sAjaxSource": 'getLists',
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "Title" , "sTitle": "Titel"},
            { "mDataProp": "Info", "sTitle": "", "sClass": "info", "mRender": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return '<a href="getLists/'+ data +'" title="Information -'+ row.Title + '" class="info">Info</a>'; }
            },
            { "mDataProp": "Min" , "sTitle": "Min"},
            { "mDataProp": "Price" , "sTitle": "Preis"},

        "fnDrawCallback": function() {
            //bind the click handler script to the newly created elements held in the table
            $('tbody td.info a.info').bind('click',DialogInformation);
        }
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.bind() attaches the click event at 'domready'. Attach the event handler using .on like this

```
$('tbody').on('click', 'td.info a.info',DialogInformation);
```

Comment: This can be done in the `ready()` itself no need to use the `fnDrawCallback`